# NodeJS is using a lot of heap memory when nothing is happening

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I have the following code saved to `test.js`:

```js
setInterval(logMemoryUsage, 5000);

function logMemoryUsage() {
  const formatMemoryUsage = (data) => `${Math.round((data / 1024 / 1024) * 100) / 100} MB`;
  const memoryData = process.memoryUsage();
  console.log({
    rss: `${formatMemoryUsage(memoryData.rss)}`,
    heapTotal: `${formatMemoryUsage(memoryData.heapTotal)}`,
    heapUsed: `${formatMemoryUsage(memoryData.heapUsed)}`,
    external: `${formatMemoryUsage(memoryData.external)}`,
  });
}
```

I've run this code on two seperate machines (one of which was a fresh Ubuntu install), and on both the `heapUsed` is averaging around 5MB, despite my actual program not using that much:

```json
{
  rss: '24.37 MB',
  heapTotal: '5.25 MB',
  heapUsed: '4.63 MB',
  external: '0.32 MB'
}
```

I understand that JavaScript is a JIT & garbage-collected language, and that node has other stuff it's doing behind the scenes, but *5 MB?* It seems like an awful lot.

For reference, I encountered this on v16.18.1 and v18.12.1.

What is causing this, and is there anything I can do to reduce the amount of memory used by my node app?

Thanks.

Comment: 5MB for an interpreted language with all these libraries is basically nothing these days.  If you want ultra small memory usage, then use a lower level language where you directly control everything.  If you're running this in an 8GB system, that's less than 0.1% of system memory.

Comment: Not able to reproduce : https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-fm29ls?file=index.js

Comment: To add to what @jfriend00 said, Node on my workstation uses about 7MB just running a REPL, not doing anything. Compared to Python (22MB) or the JVM or CLR (hundreds of megs), 5MB is really nothing — but if you need to run JS in a low-resource situation, you could look at `max_old_space_size`, or a different JS engine like Duktape or Elk.

Comment: FYI, I used to write and run programs in 32k of memory, but these were hand crafted in assembly language and had NONE of the tools/libraries available in a high level interpreted language with garbage collection.  So, it can be done, but nodejs is not the tool if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jfriend00 This question was asked due to a friend mentioning they were running node apps on ~20 KB of memory. I was pretty sure this wasn't true, but I asked this question anyways, and upon double checking, they did indeed realize that it was ~ 20 MB and not KB. But just so I'm set moving forward, are there any specific things I can do to catch memory leaks and keep general memory usage low?

Comment: General memory usage will usually be dominated by how many large things you have in memory (large arrays, large buffers, large numbers of some type of object, etc...).  So, keeping memory usage low is really no different than in any other language.  The more large in-memory stuff you keep persistent, the higher your memory usage will be. In a GC language, it is often the peak memory usage that gets you, not the idle memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

> 5 MB? It seems like an awful lot.

Indeed, it is. Welcome to JavaScript. This memory is used for language-level built-in objects (like `Math`, `String`, `Date`), as well as environment-specific globals (e.g. `document` in the browser, `fs`, `net`, `vm` in Node).

Run this script to get an idea of just how much stuff there is by default:

```
let g_discovered = new Set();
function Discover(obj, path) {
  g_discovered.add(obj);
  let properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
  for (let p of properties) {
    try {
      let v = obj[p];
      if (v === null) continue;
      if (g_discovered.has(v)) continue;
      let nested_path = path.length > 0 ? path + "." + p : p;
      console.log(`Some memory is used by ${nested_path}`);
      if (typeof v === "object" || typeof v === "function") {
        Discover(v, nested_path);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Ignore failures. Examples that will throw:
      // Function.prototype.arguments
      // Symbol.prototype.description
    }
  }
}
Discover(this, "");
```

You could create and inspect a heap snapshot if you wanted to dig deeper.

> JavaScript is a JIT & garbage-collected language

JavaScript as a language doesn't have an opinion on whether it is interpreted, AOT-compiled, or JIT-compiled. Most modern engines have decided that a combination of interpreting and JIT-compiling is the way to go, but that's an implementation detail. If anything, this *reduces* the amount of memory that's used after initialization.

The fact that JS is garbage-collected doesn't influence the minimum memory consumption of an empty heap. It can, however, mean that e.g. the strings created by the previous run of `logMemoryUsage` haven't been freed yet (because why spend time on GC when less than 5MB are in use?).

> just so I'm set moving forward, are there any specific things I can do to catch memory leaks and keep general memory usage low?

That's a whole separate question. You can start at https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/diagnostics/memory/, and come back to StackOverflow when you have a specific problem that you can describe in detail, and where you can list steps you've already tried.